# ¿Cómo crear una nueva columna promediando los valores de otras columnas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de manipulación de dataframes en Pandas.

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
id      a   b   c
158023  159 84  95
20801   183 84  94
190871  150 79  87
193080  168 17  13
192985  154 93  82
```

A partir del siguiente dataframe, necesito crear una columna `d` que sea el promedio de la columnas `[a,b,c]`; es decir, que tome los valores de cada fila y aparezcan en una nueva columna.

¡Les agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El promedio lo calculas con `mean()`, tienes que seleccionar previamente las columnas dónde aplicar y en el eje adecuado (por fila):

```
df["d"] = df[["a", "b", "c"]].mean(axis=1)
```